# Pickle a file too large for RAM

Tags: python, python-requests, pickle

I have an extremely large file (lets say 50GB) that can't fit in RAM, obtained using `requests`:

```
req = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
```

I need to pass it into a library that internally runs `pickle.dumps(x)` on the object. I can't control how pickle is used here, so I can't try to dump each chunk individually.

If I use req.content (the entire file as one big byte string), I get a `MemoryError`, since the file is 50GB. I can access chunks of data using `req.iter_chunks()`, but pickle won't accept a generator (`TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`).

Is there any way I can stream this file object from the internet into a pickle file?

Comment: Why is `pickle` even involved here?  Just write the streamed data directly to a file as it arrives.  Wrapping it in a pickle accomplishes absolutely nothing other than making the data harder to work with later.

Comment: This is true! But as I mention in the question, it's being passed to a library that is doing the pickling (metaflow), which I have no control over.

Comment: How does it get passed into metaflow? Can you iterate over the generator yourself and feed each chunk in one at a time?

Comment: If this library insists on working only with pickles, I'd have to say that it is utterly inappropriate for working with a 50GB dataset.  There's not really any way to do anything with a pickle that doesn't require at least one side of the conversion to reside entirely in memory.

Comment: In general be careful with pickle. A pickle file can get unloadable if you have a change to your environment like: Python version, code change, library version change, OS change, machine change...